# How can you tell if a UIPrintInteractionController is showing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, airprint

Is there a way to tell if a `UIPrintInteractionController` is showing (maybe similar to the way you would check a popover)?

```
if ([popover isPopoverVisible]) {

    //the popover is visible

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you'll just have to keep track yourself with [UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate)

```
– printInteractionControllerWillPresentPrinterOptions:
– printInteractionControllerDidPresentPrinterOptions:
– printInteractionControllerWillDismissPrinterOptions:
– printInteractionControllerDidDismissPrinterOptions:
```